# Would like to apply sort to filtered results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ado.net

I would like to filter entries in my database, then apply an ascending/descending sort to filtered results. However, I don't know how to do this! I can either filter or sort, but if I filter, then apply the sort, the filter is cleared.

My controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string cityString, string specialtyString)
{
    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    ViewData["nameFilter"] = searchString;
    ViewData["cityFilter"] = cityString;
    ViewData["specialtyFilter"] = specialtyString;

    var providers = from p in _context.Provider
                    select p;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        providers = providers.Where(s => s.ProviderName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cityString))
    {
        providers = providers.Where(s => s.City.Contains(cityString));
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(specialtyString))
    {
        providers = providers.Where(s => s.ProviderType.Contains(specialtyString));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            providers = providers.OrderByDescending(m => m.ProviderName);
            break;

        default:
            providers = providers.OrderBy(m => m.ProviderName);
            break;
    }

    return View(await providers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
}
```

-and the corresponding view (partial):

```
<th>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProviderName)</a>
</th>
```

I would like for the filter parameter(s) to persist until the user clicks an affordance to clear them.

Thank you for the insights and advice!

Comment: Your code looks like it should be okay. What is happening that you want to change? Are you passing in the previous filter values to your method?

Comment: What is occurring is if I pass a filter string over the entries and return the results, I would then like to be able to sort the results in ascending or descending order. However, when I click the column header to activate the sort, the filter is removed and all results are returned to the view. I would like the filter to persist through the sort command, so that only the filtered results are sorted and displayed.

Comment: You say *then*. That means you have to re-enter the filter values into the `Index` method when you sort.

Comment: Your code should work without a problem. By reading your question and the above comment, I'm sure that when you're getting all results sorted, then `searchString`, `cityString` and `specialtyString` are either `null` or empty strings, and that's why filters are not applied. So the problem is with how you're executing `Index` method, or in other words, the problem is with `URL` parameters when requesting `Index` page.